# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Model keeps trying to create ApplicationUsers table in DB when Migration is run

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a Chat project that references an Auth project. One of the items that was referenced was

> AuthProject.Data.Models;

which contains a class called ApplicationUsers. This table has already been created in the database and in the model "ChatParticipant", I want to make a reference/foreign key to that table with ParticipantId.

```
public class ChatParticipant
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public ChatSession Session { get; set; }
    public string ParticipantId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUsers Participant { get; set; }
}
```

However, what happens when I run my migration is that a new ApplicationUsers table is created instead of linking to the old one. This application shares the same database as Auth project.

How can I prevent ApplicationUsers from being created?

Startup.cs dbContext definition

```
services.AddDbContext<AuthProjectDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DatabaseConfiguration:ConnectionString"]));
services.AddDbContext<ChatSampleDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DatabaseConfiguration:ConnectionString"]));
```

ChatSampleDbContext:

```
public ChatSampleDbContext(DbContextOptions<ChatSampleDbContext> options) : base(options) {

}
UniqueKeyGenerator uniqueKeyGenerator = new UniqueKeyGenerator();
public DbSet<ChatMessage> ChatMessage { get; set; }
public DbSet<ChatParticipant> ChatParticipant { get; set; }
public DbSet<ChatSession> ChatSession { get; set; }


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(ConfigurationManager.GetBasePath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CENTRAL_APPLICATION_SETTINGS")))
    .AddJsonFile("cssettings.json")
    .Build();
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema: configuration["DatabaseSchemas:ChatSample"]);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    Audit();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    Audit();
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
}

private void Audit()
{
    var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is ChatSession && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((ChatSession)entry.Entity).CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    ((ChatSession)entry.Entity).CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

AuthProject DbContext:

```
public class AuthProjectDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AuthProjectDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthProjectDbContext> options) : base(options) {

    }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUsers> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
    UniqueKeyGenerator uniqueKeyGenerator = new UniqueKeyGenerator();


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(ConfigurationManager.GetBasePath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CAS")))
        .AddJsonFile("mssettings.json")
        .Build();
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema: configuration["DatabaseSchemas:AuthProject"]);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        Audit();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        Audit();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private void Audit()
    {
        var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is ApplicationUsers && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((ApplicationUsers)entry.Entity).CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
        ((ApplicationUsers)entry.Entity).UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the ef model definitions please?

Comment: um..sorry which EF Model definition? As in the migration or the ApplicationUsers model?

Comment: You are using EntityFramework, aren't you? So there must be a definition of your database model. Also the Startup-Code might be relevant.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what a database model is. I put the definitions of my dbcontext in the question. Those are from startup.cs.

Comment: I'm using EntityFramework but I'm still learning around it

Comment: Can you show the DbContext code from both cotnexts? In there the model must be defined

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=efcore-2.1

Comment: I added my AuthProject and ChatSample dbcontexts

Comment: You have two contexts. The second one doesn't know about the first one. 
I would strongly suggest you to read about entity-framework core and do some tutorials because this is not the way you should use it.

One good starting point:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Comment: Yeah I set 2 contexts because I needed both of them. But they read off a common database connection string.

Comment: I have another project that is similar to this. But that one seems to be fine. I think its because I referenced ApplicationUsers that this migration then began to create it.

Comment: I just tested it. If I remove my reference to ApplicationUsers, the migration doesn't contain it.